# How can I increase the space after ":" and before the page numbers in bib entries of type article?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, custom-bib, bibliographystyle

I am using the `makebst` utility to organize the way references are formatted, and I want to adjust it to get extra horizontal space between ":" and the page number for entries of type `@article`. How do I do it?

[image: Reference]
[newstyle.bst](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nAYlLiKwmafoyDhEb86VD8cjRG2WgLc9/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments and suggestions:

- Since we're dealing with the formatting of entries of type `@article`, it sounds like a good idea to start by looking into how the `article` function is defined in the `bst` file. The `article` function starts on line 937 in the bst file to which you provided a hyperlink.
- In the `article` function, one finds calls to several additional functions (along with a couple of input sanity checks): `format.authors`, `format.date`, `format.title`, `journal`, `itlB` (to typeset the journal name in ***bold italics***), `format.vol.num.pages`, and `format.note`.
- `format.vol.num.pages` sounds promising, so let's look at its definition, which starts on line 803. The function contains calls to yet further functions: `volume`, `bolden` (to make the volume number **bold**), `number` (to process the `number` field and surround it with parentheses), and `format.journal.pages` (or, in case the entry's `eid` field is non-empty,  `format.journal.eid`).
- `format.journal.pages` sounds promising; its definition starts on line 776.

  After a few input sanity checks are performed (e.g., what to do if an entry has duplicate `pages` fields -- don't laugh, it can and does happen), the first substantive instruction in that function is contained in the following line:

  ```
            ":" *
  ```

  If you're guessing that this instruction outputs a `:` (colon) character, you'd be entirely correct. Change this line to

  ```
            ": " *
  ```

  if you want the colon character to be followed by an inter-word space. Or, if you prefer an unbreakable "thinspace", change the line to

  ```
            ":\," *
  ```
- Finally, save the bst file and re-run both BibTeX and LaTeX on your main tex file to propagate the changes.

Happy BibTeXing!